# IOS Swift Google place API how to customize the placePicker

Tags: ios, swift

Is there anyway we can customize the `google` `IOS` `GMSPlacePicker`? such as to change the image of the pin or to turn off the marks like restaurants, bars or even to add buttons over it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The only customization offered is inside the [GMSPlacePickerConfig](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_place_picker_config) class - it only allows you to change the viewport, *by far* not the things you're looking for.

Comment: Hi, I am just curious about this, I was looking at other projects that people have made using the Places API like this: https://developers.google.com/maps/showcase/#ios and for the project called Foodspotting, it says they used the Places API and Autocomplete API. They also have been able to change certain marks to images instead of the default marks Google has provided. Is there any details or method on how to replicate something they've done in the projects listed on that link?

Comment: As far as I can see, those are `GMSMarker`s with a custom icon.

Comment: Ah okay. So would it be safer to say that maybe instead of using the Places API they used the Maps API with custom GMSMarkers? Because I looked through the Places API and it just seemed a little difficult to edit the GMSMarkers only via the Places API.

Comment: I think all examples in that gallery use the Maps API. They might very well use the Places API but that isn't clear from the pictures.

Comment: Ah thanks then, I really appreciate all the clarification and help!

Comment: I figured it out by adding an imageview in the center of the screen as a layer above the map.

Answer (score 0):

### Google has recently updated their API and the GMSPlacePicker is now deprecated (support stops May 2018) which gives you a bit of time to migrate everything in your app.

> Notice: The implementation of the place picker has changed. As of
>   version 2.3 of the Google Places API for iOS, the GMSPlacePicker class
>   is deprecated, replaced by GMSPlacePickerViewController. Use of the
>   GMSPlacePicker class will only be supported until May 1, 2018. We
>   recommend that you update your code to use
>   GMSPlacePickerViewController when possible.

Upgrade to version 2.3 to access this new feature.

The new system is relatively simple to implement. You now confirm to:

> GMSPlacePickerViewControllerDelegate

And you then have access to method such as didPick() or didCancel()...

The good thing when it comes to customizing your UI is that since everything is now managed via a ViewController you can add it to your Navigation Controller stack for example and it can inherit from the navigation bar design you have set on other ViewControllers that are also in your stack either before or after the placePicker.

I'm at work now but will edit my answer with a sample code later.

More info see the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/placepicker

And when you set your placePicker, **do not forget to set your delegate to self** to ensure the methods didPick / didCancel will fire properly. If you forget you will get the following warning when you try to pick or cancel the picker. This is not written in the documentation but is obviously necessary.

> Places API warning: A delegate has not been set on an instance of
>   GMSPlacePickerViewController before use. Note that this may result in
>   undefined behavior such as being unable to dismiss screens, not being
>   notified of selections, and being unable to correctly manage object
>   lifecycle.

Hope it helps.

Ed